# Scrambling the Image

Tags: matlab, encryption

I want to scramble the image using matlab using the algorithm:

1. Converting the image to gray scale of W X H pixels.
2. Computing the sum of every row and every column.
3. Generating the random variables Kc and Kr of range (2^bit depeth-1) of h&w elements respectively.
4. Finding the modulo2 of the sum.
5. Rotate the ith  row by Kr(i) amount right if modulo2 of sum of rows is zero else rotate it left by kr(i) amount. Similarly for the columns.
6. Show the image

Problem is in using the circshift command in matlab to rotate the ith row by Kr(i) amount. This function is not using the indexing of the particular row or column.

```
%%Encryption till scrambled image
rgb = imread('image.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(rgb);
[w,h]=size(I);
imshow(I);
title('Original grayscale');
info = imfinfo('image.jpg');
bit=info.BitDepth;      
range=(2^bit)-1;
    Kc=randi(range,[1,h]);       %generating a random array Kc of h
    Kr=randi(range,[1,w]);       %generating random array Kr

    alpha=sum(I);     %sum of all column element creating an linear array of h columns
    alpha1=sum(I,2); %sum of all row element creating an linear array of w rows

     M=mod(alpha,2); %linear array of h column
     M1=mod(alpha1,2); %linear array of w rows
     for i=1:h
     if M(1:i)==0
       I1=circshift(I(:,i),-Kc(i));      %shifts up
     else
      I1=circshift(I(:,i),Kc(i));        %shifts down
     end
     end

  for j=1:w
     if M1(j:1)==0
       I2=circshift(I1(j,:),Kr(j));      %shifts right
     else
      I2=circshift(I1(j,:),-Kr(j));     %shifts left
     end
 end
 figure
 imshow(I2);
 title('Scrambled Image');`
```

Comment: `circshift` acts on an array with  >1 row.  Try  `circshift(I1(j,:)')` .  And read the help file!  :-)

Comment: Thanks Carl!.It works